# Having trouble creating linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, string, linked-list

I have an array of strings that I'm supposed to create a linked list with. The problem is I can only use arrays. Everything I've looked up says to use struct and nodes, and I'm not sure where to go from here. I know my code isn't right, I have the pointers pointing to one element of the array each, so they aren't really linked. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be amazing

Here is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{
string names [4] = {"Dick", "Harry", "Sam", "Tom", " "};
string *nameptr[4];

for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
{
    nameptr[x] = &names[x];
    cout << *nameptr[x] << " is at position " << x << " and points to ";
    cout << &nameptr[x] << endl;
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: There are so many questions about linked lists... have you looked at some for guidance?

Comment: names has 5 elements but you initialized with 4 only :)

Comment: @MartinshShaiters yeah?

Comment: @jogojapan It's that time of the year, when 1st year CS students get their assignments in data structures. :D

Comment: @blizz So there are 5 initializers. Or what?

Comment: @Martinsh Yeah. 5 initializers for `string names [4]`.

Comment: @billz ya I was tyring to get the last element to zero or null to make it the end of the list, but couldn't quite figure it out. I guess I forgot to remove the 5th

Comment: or make your array size 5. note: empty string doesn't mean NULL

Comment: @jogojapan I've looked all over to make a linked list using only arrays, but I couldn't find anything helpful. The instructor doesn't know c++ so we don't get any sample code or anything to help us out either. He just draws diagrams all day about how it's supposed to work :(

Comment: @billz Derp is me. I see what you meant, now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial for linked lists in c++:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/31357-c-linked-lists-custom-linked-lists-part-1/

You should search and have a go first in future, then when you ask people here will be able to better help you with your question. In fact read this as well:

http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I'm not allowed to use structs. I'm only allowed to use arrays. I know how to make a linked list using structs, but limited to just arrays I'm kinda stuck

Comment: Are you sure you cant use arrays, a linked list without doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if using arrays, you only need a pointer to the first element, and you can access the rest of the array by pointer arithmetic.

However, if you want a real link list. then you could do something like this:

```
struct mydata{
    std::string data;
    struct mydata* next;
}

mydata names[4] = {{"Dick",NULL}, {"Harry",NULL}, {"Sam",NULL}, {"Tom",NULL}, {" ",NULL}};
//here you establish the link
names[0].next = &names[1];
names[1].next = &names[2];
names[2].next = &names[3];
names[3].next = &names[4];
//here is the pointer to the head;
mydata* nameptr = names;

while(nameptr)
{
    cout << nameptr->data;
    nameptr = nameptr->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "I can only use arrays"?  You only know how to use arrays, or you are limited to only using arrays, or ??

You've looked up some stuff that's told you to use structs - have you tried doing this?  It isn't in your code here.

Unrelated to your actual question, but you've declared an array of 4 strings (`string names [4]`), then you're trying to initialise that array with 5 items.

My advice is similar to what you've seen: use structures, and I'll add that you're going to need to use the heap as well (`malloc` in c, `new` in c++).  The structure will need a link pointer to the next list element, and somewhere to store the data itself, in this case probably just a `char` pointer.

Comment: The instructions say I can only use arrays. If I could use structs I'd have this done by now. About trying to initialize the array with 5 items, I was trying something that didn't work, and forgot to remove that last part with the rest of the discarded code.